# @ControllerAdvice response body is always null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to set the body of the response as the error message of the exception:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(value = EntityNotFoundException.class)
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotFound(EntityNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {

    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, ex.getMessage(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT, request);

  }
}
```

I'm testing it with `restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class)`however all I can seem to get is a `418 null` response.

I know execution enters here as the response is `418`, and I know the message isn't null as it's printing the value I want.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide information about configuration of your `RestTemplate` or what the calling code looks like so I'm going to make some assumptions and you can correct me if any of these are wrong.

1. Your RestTemplate is using DefaultResponseErrorHandler
2. You're using a generic catch (Exception ex) block

If these are true then your RestTemplate is going to throw HttpClientErrorException when it encounters a 4XX status code. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/8fc16fc9378ec7ee5a51337a62b6eb46294461e9/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java#L90).

The response body will not be available if you are just using a generic `catch (Exception ex)` block. You can access the response body by adding a `catch(HttpClientErrorException ex)` block and getting the content from `ex.getResponseBodyAsString()`

Comment: Thanks. I was catching the specific exception but wasn't using getResponseBodyAsString(). Is there a way to implicitly handle these exceptions in RestTemplate config, or should each RestTemplate call try/catch them individually?

Comment: @kaybee99, What do you mean by implicitly handle them? Do you have an example of what you are looking to achieve?